# How to make a comment summary in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, comments

just a small query.

I am working in VS 2008 and often i need to write a note in code like a reminder type.
This note is in comment but is of multiple lines. i know VS used to provide summary option 
but now i am unable to find it .

a+b;  // this is my note
       //  note continuing on next line
       // but dont want to write comment slashes every time

Answer (score 0):

try these

/* */

Comment: what i am looking for is somthing that i put /// three slashes and VS will create a summary comment by itself using /* */