# String to Function Name in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, plugins

I saw in a screencast a while ago (since forgotten which, probably a Kata) where a person was writing out a unit test but wrote something like this:

`public "return zero for an all gutter game"`

Then they magically turned it into

`public returnZeroForAnAllGutterGame`

Is there a plugin for this or just a simple way to do a template that gets fired off on a key stroke?

I googled around and just couldn't think of a good way to type in a search to get what I wanted.

Comment: Usually, people want *less* typing in their IDE, not *more.* :-)

Comment: @kindall: But it may be faster to type because **1)** we are use to typing with the space bar, and **2)** having to capitalize each letter of new word slows things down too. I'm interested in this plug-in as it seems to have some potential.

Comment: I dunno, you still need two shifts to type the quotes, plus at least two keystrokes to invoke the plug-in.  Seems like it would be hard to come out ahead.

Comment: It isn't exactly all about a frustration about typing to much. Although it feels a lot less awkward to me to hit space between words instead of holding shift and hitting the first letter of the next word. 

More of this is about the need to write unit test names less "systemy". I feel that I write better and think better when writing out a sentence rather than thinking of it as a function name. Yes, I understand i just need to think differently about it and still do camel case but I think this would make things flow a lot better in a workflow. Esp in a BDD workflow where you start with stories

Comment: @James, isn't it *more* ackward to type that which is *not* going to match your code?  Strange one would eschew a one-to-one correspondence with what they type and what they see.

Comment: @Matt Spinelli 1) Using the Shift Key is now ingrained with years of sentence capitalization and CamelCase 2) It takes me time to switch contexts -- I can much more easily see "AbcData" -> "AbcData" than "abc data" -> "AbcData" 3) I'd just like `C-x b` in VS2010 -- that would save me *considerable real world non-hypothetical* time :(

Comment: @Kirk It would seem to be more awkward if I was writing out generic function names, but this is more to be used from a testing stand point. I didn't exactly make that clear. (And you probably didn't get time to see my edit in my comment)

Comment: @kindall If it was a tempalte being run then you could simplify it even more. I want it to make me a Test Harness.. so you write a sentance and it turns it into [TestMethod()] public void SentanceIsHere() {}

Then that way you are saving tons and tons of keystrokes. I am just unsure of how the tool worked in the first place.

Comment: I also saw somebody write a summary comment using /// and it turned into a summary, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297700/how-to-make-a-comment-summary-in-vs2008 Does anybody know how to do tht

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find the plugin or macro you refer to, but I did create a macro that will work nicely!

**First, to install do the following:**

1. Press Alt+F11
2. Expand MyMacros
3. Open the EnvironmentEvents module
4. Past the code into the module (code is found at the end of this post)
5. Close the macro editor

**To use the macro:**

1. Press  `` ` `` ([grave](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/60/index.htm) key).
2. Next press `"`
3. Type the words you desire
4. End by typing `` "` ``
5. Watch the magic happen!

**NOTE:** You could just start typing a sting value then latter add the grave symbols before and after and it will still work.

The macro will remove spaces and then PascalCase the entire set of words. It also strips out single and double quotes. Lastly, it will convert commas to underscores if you want to use the naming convention suggested by Roy Osherove (*The Art of Unit Testing*, p. 211):

> MethodUnderTest_Scenario_Behavior()

---

### Examples:

```
public void `"return zero for an all gutter game"`

public void `"LoadMainParts, when materials files are valid, will return a list of parts sorted by sequential item number ascending"`
```

...will turn into this (after the second `` ` `` press):

```
public void ReturnZeroForAnAllGutterGame    

public void LoadMainParts_WhenMaterialsFilesAreValid_WillReturnAListOfPartsSortedBySequentialItemNumberAscending
```

---

### The Macro:

```
...

Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

...

Private isPascalCaseAndSpaceRemovalEnabled As Boolean

Private Function ConvertToPascalCase(ByVal value As String) As String
    'apply ToUpper on letters preceeded by a space, double quotes, or a comma'
    Dim pattern As String = "[ ,"",\,][a-z]"
    value = Regex.Replace(value, _
                          pattern, _
                          Function(m) m.Value.ToUpper, _
                          RegexOptions.Singleline)

    'replace commas with underscores'
    value = value.Replace(",", "_")

    'remove spaces, graves, double quotes, and single qoutes'
    Dim removalCharacters As String() = {" ", "`", """", "'"}
    For Each character In removalCharacters
        value = value.Replace(character, "")
    Next

    Return value
End Function

Private Sub TextDocumentKeyPressEvents_AfterKeyPress(ByVal Keypress As String, _
                                                     ByVal Selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection, _
                                                     ByVal InStatementCompletion As Boolean) _
                                                     Handles TextDocumentKeyPressEvents.AfterKeyPress

    If isPascalCaseAndSpaceRemovalEnabled AndAlso Keypress = "`" Then
        Selection.SelectLine()

        Dim pattern As String = "`""(.*)""`"
        Dim substringToReplace As String = Regex.Match(Selection.Text, _
                                                       pattern, _
                                                       RegexOptions.Singleline).Value
        Selection.ReplacePattern(pattern, _
                                 ConvertToPascalCase(substringToReplace), _
                                 vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression)

        Selection.MoveToPoint(Selection.BottomPoint)

        isPascalCaseAndSpaceRemovalEnabled = False
        CancelKeyPress = True

    ElseIf Keypress = "`" Then
        isPascalCaseAndSpaceRemovalEnabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Feel free to tailor the code to your needs.